# enable ribbon button when multi select items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ribbon

I've added a ribbon button in my list created in sharepoint designer but when i select multiple items it becomes disabled.
Do you know a way to enable the ribbon for multi selection

i found this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/33649824-5e2f-489a-a1cf-1b1fa333d31f/need-a-script-for-the-ribbon-button-click-event-to-copy-all-the-multiple-selected-items-in-the?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

but i don't understand where i've to put this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up button as "navigate to url", it will be a active even with multiple selected list item.

Comment: where can i set the button as navigate to url? i created a custom action on my list in SPD

Comment: i see what you sayied and it's already the case because i execute some javascript